# Remove default LWC Tooltip "This property supports using an expression to define its custom label"

Tags: lightning-web-components, xml, properties, config

In our organisation we have some LWC with configurable fields in the XML

[image]

As you can see, some of them have description and others have not.

Even for the ones that have a description, the help text that appears in the builder has a default text "This property supports using an expression to define its custom label".

[image]

Do you know if there's a way to remove this default text that appears, and only show the defined description?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Something seems off there, namely that you have a label defined for that property which says "Button Action", but it's still showing up in the designer as "TypeAction"...  Have you tried redeploying?

Comment: Good point! but this is a problem on the screenshots but it was deployed to the same org several times and this text is added after the description (we tried to change description, and it changed but added the extra text). I think this is standard but maybe there's a way to remove it.